# Itunes backup for Iphone folder on Windows 10?

Tags: backup

I'm doing really hard on finding the backup folder, that Itunes uses for my Iphone 6s. The Backup worked fine, but I cannot find any Apple or Apple Computer folder in my AppData folder, which I access over %AppData% in my search bar. I also cannot find the place, where Itunes is installed, also the option when I right click on the Icon to go to the link folder destination does not show up.

Why is Itunes hidden like a needle in a haystack? Anyone an idea, why I have no Apple or Apple Computer folder in my metadata folder AppData?

Answer (score 2):

If you install iTunes using the Microsoft Store on Windows 10, the iTunes backup location is `%userprofile%\Apple\MobileSync\Backup` instead. Try pasting that in to the search bar. I believe the change is due to rules about where apps on the Microsoft Store are supposed to store data. Here's a blog post I wrote going over the [iTunes backup locations on different platforms](https://deciphertools.com/blog/where-are-iphone-backups/) as a reference.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I found it, it is not in the AppData es described on the Apple homepage ([Itunes Backup Folder](https://support.apple.com/lt-lt/HT204215#findiTunes)), but in the user folder on Windows:

~/User/Username/Apple/MobileSync/Backup